# Запуск окна командной строки со встроенной командой

Tags: cmd

Требуется, чтобы окно командной строки запустилось и сразу же началось выполнение указанной команды.

Если точнее, хочу это проделать с ярлыком `cmd.exe`.

Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 6):

Выше сказанное запустит указанную команду, однако, после её выполнения окно тут же закроется. Чую, неспроста автор хочет запустить именно cmd, подозреваю, есть желание лицезреть окно консоли даже после завершения команды. Следующий вариант запуска даст сей эффект

```
  start call ipconfig
```

Comment: Совсем необязательно было делать ответ общим. Может быть, вы случайно его таким сделали?

Comment: Действительно, случайно. Просто набрал ответ и нажал единственную кнопку в мобильной версии сайта "ответить", как он стал "общим", как и значение этого статуса ответа для меня пока загадка. Никаких похожих кнопок в мобильной версии не наблюдаю. Я бы и коментом ответил, да "карма" не позволяет.

Comment: можете здесь об этом почитать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже добрался до стационарного ПК, так что все уже и сам выяснил.

Comment: похоже, модератор восстановил вам авторство ответа.

Answer (score 3):

оч просто: напиши команду в notepad и сохрани с расширением .bat

> When a batch file is run, the shell program (usually COMMAND.COM or
>   cmd.exe) reads the file and executes its commands, normally
>   line-by-line. Unix-like operating systems (such as Linux) have a
>   similar, but more flexible, type of file called a shell script. The
>   filename extension .bat is used in DOS and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

К выше сказанному но на пальцах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

еще не забывать , что многие команды требуют прав админа , поэтому клацайте по файлику правой кнопкой и жмите "Запуск от имени админа"